# If $G$ is a group. Let $H$ be a normal $p$-nilpotent subgroup of $G$ and let $N$ be a minimal normal subgroup of $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

If $G$ is a group. Let $H$ be a normal $p$-nilpotent subgroup of $G$ and let $N$ be a minimal normal subgroup of $G$ whose order is divisible by $p$. If $[H,N]\neq 1$ then $H \cap N \neq 1$ ?? This is true ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try to explain the answer of Derek Holt,

Let $H$,$K$ be normal subgroups of $G$,

$$[h,k]=hkh^{-1}k^{-1}$$

Notice that $hkh^{-1}\in K$ as $K$ is normal so $hkh^{-1}k^{-1}\in K$.

Similirly, $kh^{-1}k^{-1}\in H$ as $H$ is normal so $hkh^{-1}k^{-1}\in H$.

As a result $[h,k]\in H\cap K$. Hence $[H,K]\leq H\cap K$.

Answer (score 3):

Yes because $H,N \unlhd G$ implies $[H,N] \le H \cap N$ (the other hypotheses are not needed ).